# Pandas left join between datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I have to dataframes - `df` and `gdf`

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

data = [['foo', datetime(2020,1,1,0,0,0) ], ['foo', datetime(2020,2,1,0,0,0)], ['foo', datetime(2020,3,1,0,0,0)],
       ['bar', datetime(2020,4,1,0,0,0)],['bar', datetime(2020,5,1,0,0,0)],['bar', datetime(2020,6,1,0,0,0)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'timestamp'])

data = [['A', datetime(2020,1,15,0,0,0), datetime(2020,3,15,0,0,0) ], ['B', datetime(2020,4,15,0,0,0),datetime(2020,6,15,0,0,0)]]
gdf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['geoid', 'starttime', 'endtime'])


df
    id  timestamp
0   foo 2020-01-01
1   foo 2020-02-01
2   foo 2020-03-01
3   bar 2020-04-01
4   bar 2020-05-01
5   bar 2020-06-01

gdf
    geoid starttime     endtime
0   A     2020-01-15    2020-03-15
1   B     2020-04-15    2020-06-15
```

My goal is to left join `gdf` on `df` where `timestamp` is between the `starttime` and `endtime` so that the output looks like:

```
res
    id  timestamp   geoid
0   foo 2020-01-01  None
1   foo 2020-02-01  A
2   foo 2020-03-01  A
3   bar 2020-04-01  None
4   bar 2020-05-01  B
5   bar 2020-06-01  B
```

As far as I have researched, the only temporal join method in pandas that exists in pandas is `pandas.merge_asof()`, which does not fit this use case because the goal is to merge on between timestamps as opposed to closest.

What is the correct method in pandas (without using sqllite) to merge one table with another (left join) based on overlapping timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible use `IntervalIndex` created by `gdf` columns, then get positions by [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) and get `geoid` by indexing in numpy with `None` if `-1` (no match):

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(gdf['starttime'], gdf['endtime'], closed='both')

arr = gdf['geoid'].to_numpy()
pos = s.get_indexer(df['timestamp'])

df['new'] = np.where(pos != -1, arr[pos], None)
print (df)
    id  timestamp   new
0  foo 2020-01-01  None
1  foo 2020-02-01     A
2  foo 2020-03-01     A
3  bar 2020-04-01  None
4  bar 2020-05-01     B
5  bar 2020-06-01     B
```

Or solution with cross join with convert index of `df` to column by `reset_index` for avoid lost index values and filter in [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), last add new column by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for match by `index` column with `df.index`:

```
df1 = df.reset_index().assign(a=1).merge(gdf.assign(a=1), on='a')
df1 = df1.loc[df1['timestamp'].between(df1['starttime'], df1['endtime']), ['index','geoid']]

df['geoid'] = df1.set_index('index')['geoid']
print (df)
    id  timestamp geoid
0  foo 2020-01-01   NaN
1  foo 2020-02-01     A
2  foo 2020-03-01     A
3  bar 2020-04-01   NaN
4  bar 2020-05-01     B
5  bar 2020-06-01     B
```

Comment: using `IntervalIndex` is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy column and use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [1460]: df['tmp'] = 1
In [1461]: gdf['tmp'] = 1

In [1463]: x = df.merge(gdf) # merge on `tmp` column.

# assign None to geoid where timestamp is not in range
In [1465]: import numpy as np
In [1466]: x['geoid'] = np.where(x['timestamp'].between(x.starttime, x.endtime), x.geoid, None) 

# groupby and pick the correct geoid
In [1477]: ans = x.groupby(['id', 'timestamp'])['geoid'].first().reset_index()

In [1478]: ans
Out[1478]: 
    id  timestamp geoid
0  bar 2020-04-01  None
1  bar 2020-05-01     B
2  bar 2020-06-01     B
3  foo 2020-01-01  None
4  foo 2020-02-01     A
5  foo 2020-03-01     A
```

Answer (score 1):

One option for a non-equi join is the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/); underneath the hood it uses binary search to avoid a cartesian product; it can also handle overlapping intervals:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(
df
.conditional_join(
    gdf, 
   ("timestamp", "starttime", ">="), 
   ("timestamp", "endtime", "<="), 
    how="left")
.loc[:, ['id', 'timestamp', 'geoid']]
)

    id  timestamp geoid
0  foo 2020-01-01   NaN
1  foo 2020-02-01     A
2  foo 2020-03-01     A
3  bar 2020-04-01   NaN
4  bar 2020-05-01     B
5  bar 2020-06-01     B
```